# Mapping entities, List as a Map value. Error executing DDL "drop table if exists `single_line`" via JDBC Statement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to create an application which will save Csv file to a database.
At compilation I have an error, and data is not fully saved in MySql DB.

Every line of CVS file is a single list which is a part of a map. 
Is there problem with mapping annotation of my entities ?

Here are the entities:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Map;

@Entity
@Table(name = "map_of_single_lists")
public class MapEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity=pl.manciak.excelparser.LinesEntity.class)
@MapKeyClass(Long.class)
private Map<Long, LinesEntity> mapa;

public MapEntity() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Map<Long, LinesEntity> getMapa() {
    return mapa;
}

public void setMapa(Map<Long, LinesEntity> mapa) {
    this.mapa = mapa;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="single_line")
public class LinesEntity implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ElementCollection
private List<String> singleLine;


public LinesEntity() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<String> getSingleLine() {
    return singleLine;
}

public void setSingleLine(List<String> singleLine) {
    this.singleLine = singleLine;
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL= DEBUG

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/newapp
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

errors :

```
2020-02-25 14:40:35.187 DEBUG 6504 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table `map_of_single_lists_mapa` drop foreign key `FKqcxcam32e9xly5k8nqppj7t9u`
2020-02-25 14:40:35.203  WARN 6504 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table `map_of_single_lists_mapa` drop foreign key `FKqcxcam32e9xly5k8nqppj7t9u`" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table `map_of_single_lists_mapa` drop foreign key `FKqcxcam32e9xly5k8nqppj7t9u`" via JDBC Statement


....


2020-02-25 14:40:35.204 DEBUG 6504 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : alter table `map_of_single_lists_mapa` drop foreign key `FKmy4dokdghspd6asaa66i2r8lu`
2020-02-25 14:40:35.206  WARN 6504 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table `map_of_single_lists_mapa` drop foreign key `FKmy4dokdghspd6asaa66i2r8lu`" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table `map_of_single_lists_mapa` drop foreign key `FKmy4dokdghspd6asaa66i2r8lu`" via JDBC Statement


....


2020-02-25 14:40:35.245 DEBUG 6504 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : drop table if exists `single_line`
2020-02-25 14:40:35.248  WARN 6504 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "drop table if exists `single_line`" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table if exists `single_line`" via JDBC Statement


....


2020-02-25 14:40:35.360 DEBUG 6504 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table `single_line` (`id` bigint not null, primary key (`id`)) engine=InnoDB
2020-02-25 14:40:35.365  WARN 6504 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table `single_line` (`id` bigint not null, primary key (`id`)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table `single_line` (`id` bigint not null, primary key (`id`)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I changed properties to uptadte and it works.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

But I'm still not sure if maping is correct. In database I have lines to number 23 , and in csv file I have 100 lines